# Relative URL in Wordpress Menu

Tags: wordpress

Is this possible? I'm trying to have a global menu item that links to a relative child page:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If possible. The value will only be the text but you can put the URL you want

Comment: The issue is that the menu item is global and it needs to link to the child page of different parents: /%parent%/overview. The menu item shows up on every parent page.